# Multiple form-data file upload parameters

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ng2-file-upload

I'd like to use the [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) component on the client side and everything works so far but now I have to pass an additional parameter with every file that contains an identifier the file is attached to.
I try to set the additionalParameter property of the FileUploader object in TypeScript:

```
this.uploader.options.additionalParameter = {"issueId": result.data.id};
```

On the server I have the following method that is working except I don't get the additional parameter (issueId) set above. (.NET Core 2.0)

```
public RequestResultModel File(IFormFile file);
```

The request payload contains the parameter but in a new form-data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryegtYAcYfO3gKdk9Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="81980085.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryegtYAcYfO3gKdk9Z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="issueId"

19
------WebKitFormBoundaryegtYAcYfO3gKdk9Z--
```

How can I modify the controller method in order to read the issueId parameter as well? In a previous project I used a second parameter `public async Task<ApiResultBase> Upload(IFormFile file, string projectid)` and it worked but now I would like to use this client side component because I don't want to suck with drag and drop and I'm lazy.
I have tried to change the component's POST url after initialize (`this.uploader.options.url = "/api/Issue/File/"+result.data.id;`) but it tries to POST to the original address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on track. I have a slightly different approach you can try out.On the client, try something like:

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: url,//The enpoint you are consuming
            additionalParameter: {
                issueId: result.data.id //your parameter-remove quotes
            },
            headers: [{ name: 'Accept', value: 'application/json' }],//your custom header
            //autoUpload: true, //configure autoUpload
        });
```

The library also has `onErrorItem` and `onSuccessItem` callbacks that you can leverage like below:

```
this.uploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onErrorItem(item, response, status, headers);
this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onSuccessItem(item, response, status, headers);
```

Then(Optional) - Callbacks:

```
    onSuccessItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers:ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
            //this gets triggered only once when first file is uploaded       
     }
    onErrorItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: 
           ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
                let error = JSON.parse(response); //error server response            
            }
```

On the API side you can restructure like below - Change it to your own signature.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImages(MyFile upload)
```

Then the `MyFile` model can be something like:

```
public class MyFile
    {
        public string issueId { get; set; }        
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

To get the param and the file:

```
var file = upload.File //This is the IFormFile file
var param = upload.issueId //param
```

To save the file to disk:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! The key was the class with the two properties. (As always with POST, I don't know why I didn't tried it before.)

Comment: hey @Perrier - how did you pass IFormFile? or library managed it by itself? I see issId is passed in additionalParameter but what about file?

Comment: @neel I was using [ng2-file-upload library](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) on the client side. The files to be uploaded are in a queue property of fileDrop.uploader.

Comment: ok thanks, do you know how it would work if I have for example: MyFile model and under that one more model FileList and under that model I have IFormFile. will this work with ng2 file uploader additionalParameter?